# Dynamic height div

Tags: html, css, height

See this code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="firstrow">    

    </div>
    <div id="secondrow">
        <div class="newsrow">    </div>
        <div class="mediarow">    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdrow">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Link1</li>
        <li>Link2</li>


    </ul>
</div>
<div id="lastpart">Copyright 2004 - 2011 &copy; example.com , All rights reserved. </div>
```

I deleted all contents of `firstrow`,`newsrow`,`mediarow` and `thirdrow` for simplicity. here is my css:

```
#content{
    width:1250px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background: url("imgbg_body_03.png");
    right: 66px;
    height:2550px;

}


#firstrow{
    margin: 0px  20px 0 0;

    width:195px;
    float:right;
}

#secondrow{
    background-color:#772255;
    width:740px;
    float:right;
}
.newsrow{

    width:366px;
    float:right;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#660066;
    /*font:bold 16px Arial;*/
}.mediarow{
    /*background:url('imgbg_index_01.png');*/
    width:366px;
    float:right;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
#footer{
    background: url("imgbg_body_02.png");
    width:1250px;
    height:38px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right:66px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#footer ul{
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px;/* 0 0 0;*/
}
#footer ul li{
    list-style-type:circle;
    display:inline;
    color:white;
    margin : 0 35px 0 35px;
    font:bold 12px Tahoma;
}
#footer ul li:hover{
    color:#FFFF00;
}
#lastpart{
    width:1250px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    background: url("imgbg_body_04.png");
    right: 66px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#660033;
    height:56px;
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

my problem is I want div with id  `content` go longer or shorter according to biggest div inside it.I tried every possible value for `Height` but no one was useful. what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try no height in content a <br style="clear: both;" /> after thirdRow. Can´t see the style of thirdRow but floats that are not cleared can get you into trouble.

Comment: @Mikael Härsjö it works but it clears their background: http://i44.tinypic.com/w9jn6r.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you close `<div id="content">` add a div with class clear and the css:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

so you html would look like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="firstrow">    

    </div>
    <div id="secondrow">
        <div class="newsrow">    </div>
        <div class="mediarow">    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdrow">

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Link1</li>
        <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="lastpart">Copyright 2004 - 2011 &copy; example.com , All rights reserved. </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a classic "CSS Guillotine". The float on the rows prevents `#container` from adjusting to their size.

Have a look at this page which explains everything:

http://css-class.com/articles/explorer/guillotine/

In short. Add this CSS to your page and put the class `clearfix` on your `#content`.

```
 <style type="text/css">

  .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    }

</style><!-- main stylesheet ends, CC with new stylesheet below... -->

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  .clearfix {
    zoom: 1;     /* triggers hasLayout */
    }  /* Only IE can see inside the conditional comment
    and read this CSS rule. Don't ever use a normal HTML
    comment inside the CC or it will close prematurely. */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

(With this solution you don't need the additional div with `clear:both`)

Comment: +1 for no additional markup elements, -1 for extra stylesheet for ie and unsemantic "clearfix" class name - i would suggest adding these rules to existing selectors. That said, I can't believe how many answers here want you to add a clear tag to the html, which is horrible advice! This is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contain floats, i believe you can actually (surprisingly) do so with the overflow property;

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can find another, more cross browser, method here: http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/

Answer (score 0):

You should put this :

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

between each div.

(between : `<div id="content">`,`<div id="footer">` and `<div id="lastpart">`.)